# Is there a way to measure time between breakpoints without stopping in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

If I put down 2 breakpoints I can measure the time between hitting the breakpoints. This is displayed in the 'Diagnostic Tools' window under the tab 'events'.

> When the debugger stops execution at a breakpoint or stepping operation, the elapsed time between the break and the previous breakpoint appears as a tip in the editor window. For more information, see PerfTips: Performance Information at-a-glance while Debugging with Visual Studio.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/perftips?view=vs-2019#perftips-1

However most of the time I setup the breakpoints to continue executing and show a message in the output instead, like so:

[image: Breakpoint settings]

The problem is, these don't show up in the 'events' tab and therefore I cannot see the execution time between hitting of the breakpoints:

[image: Diagnostic tools]

My question comes down to: **Can I get the execution time between breakpoints that continue execution instead of breaking with the visual studio debugger?**

In this particular case I'm working with an external service of sorts, and breaking the application causes issues with accurate measuring of the time and other side effects. The point is, I cannot and prefer not to use a regular breakpoint.

Please note that I'd like get information about the visual studio debugger and not a separate performance profiling tool or something like that, I'm just wondering if this is possible.

Comment: your better off using a Stopwatch. Also bear in mind that timings inside an attached debugger will not reflect production code.

Comment: @Liam Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer me. I'd rather not use stopwatch because that would add code to the codebase. We only use DEBUG configurations so I also cannot use compiler directives to omit such code when deploying my app (aside from timing discrepancies between configurations). I'm too unfamiliar with how the debugger works inernally and how it hooks into application code - but would timing really get influenced by the attached debugger? what order of magnitude am i looking at?

Comment: afaik you can configure breakpoints to only output something but not pause execution. And you can even configure them to output e.g. `DateTime.Now.Ticks` or something. That would still need you to calculate the differences to the previous outputs yourself, though.

Comment: May i ask? Do your code do any kind of logging what it does while its running? And if not, why?

Comment: Use [EventSource](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-samples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing/EventSource/docs/EventSource.md#typical-customizations), raise Start and Stop event (with same Task) and calculate the duration in Perfview